# How to create a generic static dictionary in a static class

Tags: c#, generics, static

```
    public static class Tracking
    {

        public static List<TrackList<T>> Lists = new List<TrackList<T>>();

        public static List<TrackedDictionary<K,V>> Dictionaries =new List<TrackedDictionary<K,V>>()

        public static void Register<K,V>(TrackedDictionary<K,V> dictionary)
        {
            Dictionaries.Add(dictionary);
        }

        public static void Register<T> (TrackList<T> list)
        {
            Lists.Add(list);
        }
    }

public class TrackList<T> : List<T>
    {
        private string ListName = null;
        private int AvgSize;

        public TrackList ()
        { }

        public TrackList (string listname, int avgsize)
        {
            this.ListName = listname;
            this.AvgSize = avgsize;
            Tracking.Register(this);
        }

        public int GetListSize ()
        {
            return this.Count * this.AvgSize;
        }
    }

public class TrackedDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K, V>
    {
        public string DictionaryName = null;
        public byte AvgSize;

        public TrackedDictionary ()
        { }

        public TrackedDictionary (string dictionaryname, byte avgsize)
        {
            this.DictionaryName = dictionaryname;
            this.AvgSize = avgsize;
            Tracking.Register(this);
        }

        public int GetDictionarySize ()
        {
            return this.Count * this.AvgSize;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide some more context: what is the problem you're trying to solve by the approach you want to use?

Comment: Consider reading about generics in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't declared `Tracking` as a generic type, so `T`, `K` and `V` have no meaning. You can do so easily enough:

```
public static class Tracking<T, K, V>
{
    ...
}
```

Note that you'll now have *separate* `Lists`, `Dictionaries` etc fields per concrete type. You'll need to make the methods non-generic though.

An alternative is to have a top-level non-generic class, with generic methods and generic nested types:

```
public static class Tracking
{
    private static class ListHelper<T>
    {
        internal static List<TrackList<T>> Lists = new List<TrackList<T>>();
    }

    private static class DictionaryHelper<K, V>
    {
        internal static List<TrackedDictionary<K,V>> Dictionaries =
            new List<TrackedDictionary<K,V>>()
    }

    public static void Register<K,V>(TrackedDictionary<K,V> dictionary)
    {
        DictionaryHelper<K, V>.Dictionaries.Add(dictionary);
    }

    public static void Register<T> (TrackList<T> list)
    {
        ListHelper<T>.Lists.Add(list);
    }
}
```

I'd also *strongly* advise against public fields like this... and against using statics widely to start with, given the problems they cause for testability.

Comment: I want it generic , I can't make a static class generic

Comment: Class wont be generic any more

Comment: @Amit: Yes you can. `static class Foo<T> {}` compiles with no problem. Please post the error message you're getting - perhaps you're trying to put an extension method in a generic type?

Comment: Have a look here for an exmaple of a generic static class http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/09/05/225955.aspx